# display URL in iframe loop

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I got this iframe loop,

```
if ( query.length > 0) {
            $("#iframes-container").empty();
            for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
                var result = query.results[i];
                $("<iframe />", {
                    name: 'myFrame',
                    id:   'myFrame',
                    src: result.url,
                    width: 1024,
                    height : 650
                }).appendTo('#iframes-container');
```

which works great. However if i ad

```
$("<span>"+result.url+"</span>").appendTo('#iframes-container');
```

to display the url, its always displayed right to the iframe and messes with my design.

so i added

```
span {

display: block;
```

}

which displays the url under the specific iframe, but then the design is messed up too, since iframes are not displayed next to each other anymore, but only one under the other.

So how do i get the url under the iframe and still letting iframes be placed next to eachother?

thanks

Comment: I would suggest using a floating div container class to wrap it all up.   `<div style="float: left"><iframe /><br><span></div>` and repeat that block for each unit.

Comment: was thinking of a container too, but kinda new to JavaScript, so I really dont know how to realize this. Could you show me? thanks.

Comment: answer added below with fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Use a dom-made float container to contain both the iframe and a p (or span) within the div.

HTML:

```
    <div id="iframes-container" class="clearfix"></div>
```

JS:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    $("<div />", { class: 'floater', id: 'div_'+i}).appendTo('#iframes-container');
    $("<iframe />", {  width: 1024, height : 200, id: 'iframe_'+i, src: 'http://jsfiddle.net' }).appendTo('#div_'+i);
    $("<p>result line</p>").appendTo('#div_'+i);
}
```

CSS:

```
#iframes-container { border: 1px solid #444; padding: 5px; }
.floater { float: left; width: 150px; height: 350px; border: 1px solid #333; overflow: scroll; }

.clearfix:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
line-height: 0;
height: 0;
}

.clearfix {
    display: inline-block;
}

html[xmlns] .clearfix {
    display: block;
}

* html .clearfix {
    height: 1%;
}
```

Full basic code:
http://jsfiddle.net/L3bg1w10/1/